# Как передать файл на телеграмм?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть поле с input type file (скрин ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно передать его в телеграмм, как и данные с инпутов

**инпуты так передаю (они выводятся успешно)**

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(e) {
   
        var phone  = $('#c_phone-number').val();
        var email = $('#c_email').val();  
        
            $.ajax({
                url: myajax.url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'request',
                    phone: phone, 
                    email: email,
                },
              
             }).done(function(data){

                $('#c_phone-number, #c_email ).val('');

            });
         
     return false;
        
    });
```

**на сервере так**

```js
    add_action('wp_ajax_request', 'request_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_request', 'request_action');

function request_action() {
    $chat_id = 'свой номер чата';
  $token = 'свой номер токена';

  $phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $text .= "<b>Сообщение с сайта</b>\n\n";
  $text .= "Телефон: ".$phone."\n";
  $text .= "Email: ".$email."\n";

  $text = urlencode($text);


  $str = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&parse_mode=html&text=".$text;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $str);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Я знаю, что нужно как минимум создать бота ТГ.

Comment: так бот создан, я ж коде указал. свой номер. У меня он есть

Comment: Разбейте задачу на несколько этапов проверки. 1) по клику, вывести нечто в консоль, 2) просто отработка передачи с пустой страницы, без аякс в бота. 3) любое событие аякс по клику (запись в файл например). А уж потом всё клеить. Вероятнее всего, на каком то этапе недосмотр. Кроме того, не вижу никаких проверок. Это дурной тон, если не проверять значения что пришли.

Comment: Вам следует ознакомится детальнее с API телеграмма, в вашем запросе не передаётся изображение

Comment: @Николай прав, у Вас вообще в коде нет ни слова о картинке/файле. А я не внимателен ))) Не вчитался в вопрос.